# WPF using ViewModelLocator in a wpf dll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF library project where I have a collection of views and view models. In this project I want to implement a **ViewModelLocator** (*VML*). However, going through some online resources it would seem that I need to have an App.xaml and declare my Locator here.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>        
 </Application.Resources>
```

Then in my views (xaml) I need to assign the data context

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="FooViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This makes sense to me if I'm working in a WPF Window application. But how do I go about implementing a VML in my dll project? I tried creating an App.xaml file in my dll project and injected my VML reference as such

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

But when I try to reference my Locator in my FooViewModel.xaml file I get a

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive.
```

Is it possible to have a VML in a dll project? If so, what am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: it makes little sense to assign `UserControl.DataContext` from inside UserControl to begin with. perfect UserControl can be used without DataContext, when customization is done by setting different properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `ViewModelLocator` resource, you may create an attached property to set the `DataContext` of the views in your control library:

```
namespace ControlsAndResources
{
    public class View
    {
        private static readonly ViewModelLocator s_viewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ViewModel", typeof(string), 
            typeof(ViewModelLocator), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChanged)));

        public static void SetViewModel(UserControl view, string value) => view.SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);

        public static string GetViewModel(UserControl view) => (string)view.GetValue(ViewModelProperty);

        private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl view = (UserControl)d;
            string viewModel = e.NewValue as string;
            switch (viewModel)
            {
                case "MainViewModel":
                    view.DataContext = s_viewModelLocator.MainViewModel;
                    break;
                case "FooViewModel":
                    view.DataContext = s_viewModelLocator.FooViewModel;
                    break;
                default:
                    view.DataContext = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlsAndResources" ... 
             local:View.ViewModel="MainViewModel">
```

Comment: I have a question... the last part titled Usage. Where and how in the xaml do I set that? How is it done?

Comment: @user2529011: You simply replace your current `<UserControl.DataContext>` element with `local:View.ViewModel="...."`.

Comment: @user2529011: The attached property then sets the `DataContext` using the `ViewModelLocator`.

Comment: You should *not* set the `DataContext` in the view. Just add the namespace declaration and set the property like I showed you, i.e. add this to the root element of the `UserControl`.

Comment: works now. All I had to do was was close my solution and run it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey I have a question. What if my View Models need to take in a parameter or two? What would I need to do in order to implement it?

Comment: @user2529011: That's another story. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.